# How to choose the best algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, machine-learning-model, algorithms

this might be simple  but I need to know how to choose a best algorithm based on a scenario.

I have a dataset. The target class is, let's say `color`, this `color` attribute can have upto 5 values (red, yellow, blue, green, pink)

So I have:

1.) 1 target class - `color`

2.) Multiple values for that target class - (red, yellow, blue, green, pink)

As this is a labelled dataset with known classes, I can use a `Supervised Learning Algorithm`

But I don't know which algorithm would be the best. It should be a `multi-class` classigication? Or `multi-labeled` ? Can someone help me to find the best algorithm?

note: I know choosing an algorithm depends on many factors (such as its acuracy), but at a glance, what type of algorithms should I try?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so without going in to details,

Your target values are **nominal, discrete values**, hence the **classification** model would solve your problem.

Under classification there are variety of methods available,for example, there is **decision tree, Naive Bayes** etc.. . you may try all of these and check which gives the better **confusion metrics**.

**Multi-Class** means, there are multiple classes , such as in you colors.

If I have books features as input and i want to predict its genre, and the available categories i can put this book in are- fictional, romance, historical. all these labels makes it multi class because multiple genre.A book can be of any of the genre.

**Multi-Label** means, an instance can belong to more than 1 class.

Now, if this one book is fictional romance , then this makes it multi label. Because out of 3 available categories, this one book belongs to 2(it can be more than 2 also).

Now, This was just a short answer to get you started,please read on these key words to further details.

> 1.) 1 target class - color

This is target attribute, color

> 2.) Multiple values for that target class - (red, yellow, blue, green, pink)

Multiple class/labels for target attribute, red, yellow, blue... are classes/labels. Since there are more than 2 classes its multi class.

If you input map to 2 or more colors than 1 then it makes it multi label.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. So `multi-class` means an attribute having multiple values and `multi-label` means the target can be multiple attributes. Am I right?

Comment: just added more clarification with example in answer.

Comment: Thank you now it make even more sense.

Comment: Happy to help. Accepting the answer would be nice.